# How to integrate AChartEngine with data from SQLite DB?

Tags: android, sqlite, achartengine

Hello AChartEngine is very new to me so any help is welcome. What I want to do is to display 2 data from my DB which are the BMI result and the date of it when the user saved his/her BMI result. I don't know what to do with this right now. BUt what I have is this:

My Code:
    public class ViewBMIData extends Activity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewbmidata);

    //TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvBMIData);
    //TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.tvBMIDate );

    BMICalculatorDB info = new BMICalculatorDB(this);
    info.open();

    String data1 = info.getBMIDataData();
    String data2 = info.getBMIDateData();
    for (int i = 1; data1 == null; i++) {

        double x = Double.parseDouble( data1 );
        double y = Double.parseDouble( data2 );

        }
        info.close();

    //tv1.setText( data1 );
    //tv2.setText( data2 );

}
```

This code is what I've found from tutorials but no idea how to do this:

```
    public Intent getIntent( Context context ){

            // Bar 1
            int[] y = { 124, 135, 443, 456, 234, 123, 342, 134, 123, 643, 234, 274 };
            CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("BMI");
            for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
                series.add("Bar " + (i+1), y[i]);
            }

            // Bar 2
            int[] y2 = { 224, 235, 243, 256, 234, 223, 242, 234, 223, 243, 234, 274 };
            CategorySeries series2 = new CategorySeries( "BMR" );
            for ( int i = 0; i < y.length; i++ ) {
                series2.add( "Bar " + (i+1), y2[i] );
            }

            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
            dataset.addSeries( series.toXYSeries() );
            dataset.addSeries( series2.toXYSeries() );

            // This is how the "Graph" itself will look like
            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
            mRenderer.setChartTitle( "BMI and BMR Statistics" );
            mRenderer.setXTitle( "DATE" );
            mRenderer.setYTitle( "BMI" );
            mRenderer.setAxesColor( Color.GREEN );
            mRenderer.setLabelsColor( Color.RED );

            // Customize bar 1
            XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            renderer.setDisplayChartValues( true );
            renderer.setChartValuesSpacing( ( float ) 0.5 );
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer( renderer );

            // Customize bar 2
            XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            renderer.setColor( Color.CYAN );
            renderer.setDisplayChartValues( true );
            renderer.setChartValuesSpacing( ( float ) 0.5 );
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer( renderer2 );

            Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent( context, dataset,mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT );
            return intent;

}  */
```

Please guide me in doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no better help than the tutorials and the demo program available from the AChartEngine downloads.

Comment: Yup they don't have examples that retrieve data from database?

Comment: No "they" don't. They don't have examples retrieving data from files or from network or from an Android enabled helicopter, or from...

Comment: It's not a big deal to create a renderer and a dataset and start adding data to it.

Comment: Ok. For bar 1, how do I add the date field of mine from the DB to this? // Bar 1
            int[] y = { 124, 135, 443, 456, 234, 123, 342, 134, 123, 643, 234, 274 };
            CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("BMI");
            for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
                series.add("Bar " + (i+1), y[i]);
            }

Comment: instead of int[] y how can I do it something like String data2 = info.getBMIDateData(); to display the date?

Comment: In the demo program, take a look at AbstractDemoChart. There are a lot of methods creating datasets that are called from sub-classes.

Comment: Hello this is what I've done but i got an error: BMICalculatorDB info = new BMICalculatorDB(this);
  
  String data1 = info.getBMIDataData();
  String data2 = info.getBMIDateData();
  
  info.open();
  
  CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("BMI");
  for (int i = 1; data1 == null; i++) {

   series.add("Bar " + (i+1), data1[i]);
   double x = Double.parseDouble( data1 );
   double y = Double.parseDouble( data2 );

   }
   info.close();

Comment: Please take a look at this example: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/SalesStackedBarChart.java